# php filename up to a specific character

Tags: php, wordpress

Hello I'm trying to get php to return a filename and return the string as part of a rel tag that will be used by a javascript plugin.

I need to add some php script to return the filename string up to the second hyphon:
so far i have

```
<?php 
$filename = basename ( get_attached_file( get_post_thumbnail_id() ) ); 
?>
<?php echo pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_FILENAME); ?>
```

it returns

`tulip-367-011` the filename is `tulip-367-011.jpg` how do I get it to return `tulip-367`

Hi I tried

```
<?php 
$filename = basename ( get_attached_file( get_post_thumbnail_id() ) ); 
?>
<?php echo $file_parts = explode('-', basename($filename)); 
array_pop($file_parts); // Remove the last segment 
$split_name = implode('-', $file_parts); 
?>
```

And it returned Array - Not evan a horay! That would have really made me chuckle, I've been stumped on this for week now. Thanks for the Help again I will keep trying. I'm not a very good programmer yet so please feel free to laugh at my stupidity. Asa

And I tried

```
$file_parts = explode('-', basename($filename)); 
array_pop($file_parts); // Remove the last segment 
$split_name = implode('-', $file_parts);
```

And it also said Array. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use[`basename`](http://php.net/basename) instead of `fileinfo`.

Example:

```
$file_without_extension = basename($filename)
```

**Edit**

Sorry I misread the original question, assuming the file names are consistent, to remove the last segment do something like this:

```
$file_parts = explode('-', basename($filename));
array_pop($file_parts); // Remove the last segment
$split_name = implode('-', $file_parts;
```

Comment: If you also need to remove several chars from file http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php may be helpful

Answer (score 0):

```
$fileParts = pathinfo(get_attached_file( get_post_thumbnail_id()));
$nameParts = explode('-', $fileParts['basename']);
if (count($nameParts) > 1) {
    $myName = $nameParts[0]+'-'+$nameParts[1];
} else {
    $myName = $nameParts[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it:

```
<?php 
$filename = basename ( get_attached_file( get_post_thumbnail_id() ) ); 
$file_parts = explode('-', basename($filename)); 
array_pop($file_parts); // Remove the last segment 
$split_name = implode('-', $file_parts); 
echo $split_name;
?>

<a itemprop="image" href="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id() ); ?>" class="Magic360" rel="filename:<?php echo $split_name?>-{col}.jpg; magnify:true; magnify-filename:<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'magnified_image_filename', true); ?>-{col}.jpg"><img src="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'magnified_image', true); ?>"
```